# How do I open a keyboard on a click on a react-select search bar inside a webview in a React Native application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a website written with React (https://new.sacatucita.com/).

On my website, I have a search bar using react-select (https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select).

I want to make an application showing my website with React Native, so I have this code:

```
import React from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <WebView
      originWhitelist={["*"]}
      source={{ uri: "https://new.sacatucita.com/" }}
    />
  );
}
```

The problem is that when I open my application and click on the search bar, the keyboard and results do not show. It appears that the click has no effect. I need to first click elsewhere (like on the title text for example), and then the search bah will work.

I already tried to select the webview with the ref:

```
ref={ref => {
  const e = ref && ref.webViewRef && ref.webViewRef.current;
  e && e.focus();
}}
```

And to click injecting HTML:

```
const js = `
  const e = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  e.click();
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <WebView
      originWhitelist={["*"]}
      source={{ uri: url }}
      injectedJavaScript={js}
    />
  );
}
```

I found out that the problem is only present on android devices.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

When you do this, the keyboard will come out normally.

I made a [link so you could test it yourself.](https://snack.expo.io/@taeeh/webview-test)

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://new.sacatucita.com/'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But when I click directly on the search bar, it still does not open. We still need to click somewhere else first. Here is the test I made : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_LZeG9NbyHyU8MZSb1suLwraIdSjIfh6/view?usp=sharing. (I also tested in local on my computer) And thanks for the styling btw :)